# system-properties In standalone-full.xml

Tags: jboss7.x

Jboss version: jboss-as-7.1.0.Final

can we add

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="x" value="/opt/db/common"/>
</system-properties>
```

In standalone-full.xml?

I am getting below error:

```
 20:54:35,726 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
 20:54:35,884 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
 20:54:35,942 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" starting
 20:54:36,575 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015950: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" stopped in 5ms
 20:54:36,569 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] JBAS014601: Error booting the container: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:161) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
 Caused by: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:125) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:187) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:261) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:155) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    ... 1 more
 Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[479,1]
 Message: JBAS014789: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:1.1}system-properties' encountered
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ParseUtils.unexpectedElement(ParseUtils.java:85) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readServerElement_1_1(StandaloneXml.java:350) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:126) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:100) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:117) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    ... 4 more
```

at [row,col]:[479,1] I am having below entry:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="x" value="/opt/db/common"/>
    <property name="y" value="/opt/db/engine/work/q22222-161-1/engine/info/exye/2.0/files/config.xml"/>
    <property name="z" value="/opt/db/engine/work/q22222-161-1/engine/info/exye/2.0"/>
    <property name="m" value="/opt/db/engine/work/q22222-161-1/engine/info/exye/2.0/log"/>
    <property name="n" value="Member1"/>
    <property name="log4j.ignoreTCL" value="true"/>
    <property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT" value="5000"/>
</system-properties>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

IIRC it's been fixed upstream, but some versions require the `<system-properties/>` to be directly under the `<extensions/>` tag.

Try something like:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.1">

    <extensions>
        ...
    </extensions>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="x" value="/opt/db/common"/>
        <property name="y" value="/opt/db/engine/work/q22222-161-1/engine/info/exye/2.0/files/config.xml"/>
        <property name="z" value="/opt/db/engine/work/q22222-161-1/engine/info/exye/2.0"/>
        <property name="m" value="/opt/db/engine/work/q22222-161-1/engine/info/exye/2.0/log"/>
        <property name="n" value="Member1"/>
        <property name="log4j.ignoreTCL" value="true"/>
        <property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT" value="5000"/>
    </system-properties>

    ...
</server>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer , I will try it out. by the way What IIRC  stands for ?

Comment: As of WildFly 19.1 (hello from 2020!), it still requires `<system-properties/>` to be right after `<extensions/>`