# How do I set X-FRAME-OPTIONS in JBoss EAP 6.1?

Tags: java, jboss

I am running a java spring application on Jboss EAP 6.1
X-FRAME-OPTIONS in the request header when performing a file upload is DENY and I receive the following errors. The file upload also does not appear on the page.

[image: iframe errors]

All of the solutions I see online say that I should try setting this value to SAMEORIGIN. They also show how to configure this in Apache but does anyone know how I set this option for Jboss?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the other way is to create a HTTP filter.

Create a class that implements javax.servlet.Filter
Annotate the class with @WebFilter("/*") or the context you need.

In the doFilter method set the HTTP header you need and do not forget to call chain.doFilter(request, response); afterwards.

Build this class into a JAR and make sure it is placed in your WEB-INF/lib directory.

Answer (score -2):

See the answer to this question [system-properties In standalone-full.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586657/system-properties-in-standalone-full-xml)

In your standalone XML you can set the Apache Catalina properties like this:

```
   <system-properties>
        <property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT" value="5000"/>
    </system-properties>
```

Comment: Setting this property does not appear to be a key value in apache: `Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN` [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options#Browser_compatibility)